# 1st order perturbation of energy for quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I am trying to do part B of Griffiths QM 2nd edition problem 6.2

It asks to find the 1st order correction to the energy for a perturbation of a quantum harmonic oscillator where the new spring constant is $k \rightarrow (1+\epsilon) k$

I have got that the perturbation $H'$ is

$$
\begin{align*}
H'&=V'-V\\
&=  \frac{1}{2}(1+\epsilon)kx^2 - \frac{1}{2}k x^2\\
&= \epsilon\frac{1}{2}kx^2\\
&=\epsilon V\\
\end{align*}
$$

So the 1st order correction should be

$$
\begin{align*}
E_{n1} &= <\psi_{n0}|H'|\psi_{n0}>\\
&= <\psi_{n0}|\epsilon V|\psi_{n0}>\\
&= \epsilon <\psi_{n0}| V|\psi_{n0}>\\
\end{align*}
$$

But Griffiths says to calculate this WITHOUT using any integration.

So how do you go about doing the inner product of $<\psi_{n0}| V|\psi_{n0}>$ without integration. I've seen all solutions online use virial's theorem but I am unfamiliar with the virial theorem? So is there another way to do this with out integration and without virial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without integration by writing $x$ in terms of creation ($a^{\dagger}$) and annihilation ($a$) operator.

$$x=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}(a+a^{\dagger}) $$

Operate this on $|0\rangle$ twice and take inner product of that with $\langle 0|$. This way you can get the result without integration.

Comment: Thanks Prof Shonku that definitely pointed me in the right direction. By the way, I totally disagree with the people that flagged this is as off topic for not attempting any effort to the problem. WTH?!?! Look at what I posted and the latex and what I did work through. Did you guys that flagged this even read the problem statement in Griffiths text?